# Is it possibile to get View from Fragment which is not a part of this Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-view

I have a following problem. I would like to set a `TextView` in case if the search list is empty. I am doing this like this in `onCreateView`:

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    View empty = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_empty);
    this.mList.setEmptyView(empty);
```

I have many `Fragments` in which I will have to add this `EmptyView`, but is there any way to avoid the need to add the same piece of code (below) in the .xml of each Fragment:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_list_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/empty_list"
        android:textColor="@color/main_white"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the view in the MainActivity in the center, above your fragment container.

```
//MainActivity

private TextView tvEmpty;

public void onCreate(...){
    this.tvEmpty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NameOfEmptyTV);
}

public View getEmptyTv(){
    return this.tvEmpty;
}



//FRAGMENT

public View onCreateView(...){
    this.mList.setEmptyView(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getEmptyTv());
}
```

Or you could create your own extended Fragment which already implements such methods